# vTigerCRM 5.4 New entity and field behavior

Tags: vtiger

I’m a newbie on vTiger development and I’m wondering if this feature is possible to implement:
I would like to have a new entity on vTiger for Zip Code. This entity will have the Zip Code, Street name, Neighborhood, City and State.

I would like to link the Zip Code on Contacts module to this new entity and, when someone pick up a zip code from the picklist, it will fill automatically the Street, City, State fields on Contacts.

This should work on New Record or Editing Records.

Any clue about this?

Thanks in advance and best regards,

Answer (score 0):

creating modules in vtiger easy. check vtiger payment module . bye following this sample module you willl get an idea about module development. Also have a look on developer guides